# How to use sed to replace multiline string?

Tags: sed

How can I use the bash **sed** command to change this string:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

into the following string? *(only changing the 3rd line of string)*

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**NOTE 1:** I don't just want to target the string **'AllowOverride None'** because there are other occurrences in the file that should not be changed. I need to target the entire string starting with `<Directory /var/www>`

**NOTE 2:** I also need to overwrite the file. So, take that into account in your answer. And provide different versions for GNU/non-GNU versions of sed just in case.

Comment: It would be good to have a more generic [mcve] to see what is constant and what is not: does it have to be on `/var/www`? Also, using `sed` for multiline doesn't seem to be the cleanest way: `awk` can probably handle this way better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this is not what you asked by maybe its worth not using sed?

How about a python solution? It walks directory passed as first parameter to script and replaces **exactly** `<Directory` element as you wrote it while **only** changing `None` to `All` and writes changes back to the file. It will also work with different indentation levels while preserving original indentation. Works on both python2 and python3.

After all i am assuming if you have sed you probably have python too.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re

r = re.compile(r'(<Directory /var/www/>\s+Options Indexes FollowSymLinks\s+AllowOverride )None(\s+Require all granted\s+</Directory>)', re.MULTILINE)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for file_name in files:
        if file_name.endswith('.conf'):
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
            with open(file_path) as fp:
                data = r.sub(r'\1All\2', fp.read())
            with open(file_path, 'w+') as fp:
                fp.write(data)
```

Answer (score 8):

Since the patterns contain slashes, use `\%` (for any character `%`) to mark the search patterns.  Then use:

```
sed -e '\%^<Directory /var/www/>%,\%^</Directory>% s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/'
```

The search patterns inside `\%…%` limit the search to lines between the matching patterns, and the `{ s/…/…/; }` looks for the desired pattern within the range and makes the appropriate replacement.

If you don't want to restrict it to a single directory section but to all directory sections, adjust the start pattern appropriately.  For example, this will match any `<Directory>` section:

```
sed -e '\%^<Directory [^>]*>%,\%^</Directory>% s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/'
```

You can make it more selective depending on your requirements.

Comment: I don't think OP intended to limit the replacements to just one **<Directory /var/www/>** section (but to all **<Directory ...>** sections). Besides I think, this solution will still replace ALL occurrences of **AllowOverride None** between (the first) **<Directory /var/www/>** and the last occurrence of the **</Directory>** tag.

Comment: @Leon: If the directory name doesn't matter, remove that from the first pattern in the search range.  No: it would handle each `<Directory ...>` to `</Directory>` range separately; it would not use first `<Directory` and last `</Directory>` as a single range.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I had a typo in my initial version that tried just that!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The pattern works great but how do I use it to overwrite the original file? Tried adding -i but getting nothing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler also tried outputting your command back to the original file like so: [sed command] > file.txt but that totally wiped the file blank.

Comment: Use `sed -i.bak -e '…' file.txt`.  Overwriting the input file with `> file.txt` is an expensive way to create an empty file (or zap a previously non-empty file).

Comment: @Leon yes I wanted to limit replacements to just <Directory /var/www> but having trouble applying these answers.

Comment: Cool! `\%..%` is new to me. (sed is always surprising) +1

Comment: `sed '…' file.txt > file.txt.bak && mv file.txt.bak file.txt` is more portable than using the GNU-only `-i` or the BSD-only `-i suffix`.  It also ensures that if there's an error, you don't overwrite the original file (add ` || rm file.txt.bak` to blow it away if there's a failure).

Answer (score 3):

The simple version, relying on the **AllowOverride** line coming within two lines after **<Directory...>** and using a GNU sed extension, is this:

```
sed '/^<Directory/,+2 { s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/g; }'
```

**UPDATE**: Here is the version not relying on any GNU extension (I tried it first, but made a typo and was surprised that it didn't work, that's why a posted the other version first):

```
sed '/^<Directory/,/^<\/Directory>/ { s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/; }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Gnu Sed:

```
 sed -zie 's!\(<Directory /var/www/>[^<]*AllowOverride\) None!\1 All!'  ex1.txt
```

- Option `-z` is for Null separated records: all the file is one record,
  so just make a simple substitution.
- `[^<]*` (multiline) regular expression respects Directory boundaries, and allows flexible format and order.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a good illustration of the mantra, *don't use sed*.  Really, you shouldn't use any regex engine for context-free language like XML.  But you can get close, maybe close enough, with **awk**.

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

/<Directory \/var\/www\/>/ {
    line = NR
}

/    AllowOverride None/ && line + 2 == NR {
    gsub( /None/, "All" )
}

{ print }
```

That way you don't have any fancy, nonstandard regex to read, and your code says exactly what it means: If you find "AllowOverride" 2 lines after the "Directory" line, replace it.  The above regexes are both very simple (and Posix compliant) and should work with any version of awk.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is already given by this [user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/2343/peter-o) just [check here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string).

**Some Reference**

In the simplest calling of sed, it has one line of text in the pattern space, ie. 1 line of \n delimited text from the input. The single line in the pattern space has no \n... That's why your regex is not finding anything.

You can read multiple lines into the pattern-space and manipulate things surprisingly well, but with a more than normal effort.. Sed has a set of commands which allow this type of thing... Here is a link to a Command Summary for sed. It is the best one I've found, and got me rolling.

However forget the "one-liner" idea once you start using sed's micro-commands. It is useful to lay it out like a structured program until you get the feel of it... It is surprisingly simple, and equally unusual. You could think of it as the "assembler language" of text editing.

Summary: Use sed for simple things, and maybe a bit more, but in general, when it gets beyond working with a single line, most people prefer something else...
I'll let someone else suggest something else.. I'm really not sure what the best choice would be (I'd use sed, but that's because I don't know perl well enough.)

```
sed '/^a test$/{
       $!{ N        # append the next line when not on the last line
         s/^a test\nPlease do not$/not a test\nBe/
                    # now test for a successful substitution, otherwise
                    #+  unpaired "a test" lines would be mis-handled
         t sub-yes  # branch_on_substitute (goto label :sub-yes)
         :sub-not   # a label (not essential; here to self document)
                    # if no substituion, print only the first line
         P          # pattern_first_line_print
         D          # pattern_ltrunc(line+nl)_top/cycle
         :sub-yes   # a label (the goto target of the 't' branch)
                    # fall through to final auto-pattern_print (2 lines)
       }    
     }' alpha.txt
```

Here it is the same script, condensed into what is obviously harder to read and work with, but some would dubiously call a one-liner

```
sed '/^a test$/{$!{N;s/^a test\nPlease do not$/not a test\nBe/;ty;P;D;:y}}' alpha.txt
```

Here is my command "cheat-sheet"

```
:  # label
=  # line_number
a  # append_text_to_stdout_after_flush
b  # branch_unconditional             
c  # range_change                     
d  # pattern_delete_top/cycle          
D  # pattern_ltrunc(line+nl)_top/cycle 
g  # pattern=hold                      
G  # pattern+=nl+hold                  
h  # hold=pattern                      
H  # hold+=nl+pattern                  
i  # insert_text_to_stdout_now         
l  # pattern_list                       
n  # pattern_flush=nextline_continue   
N  # pattern+=nl+nextline              
p  # pattern_print                     
P  # pattern_first_line_print          
q  # flush_quit                        
r  # append_file_to_stdout_after_flush 
s  # substitute                                          
t  # branch_on_substitute              
w  # append_pattern_to_file_now         
x  # swap_pattern_and_hold             
y  # transform_chars
```