# Create sqlite3 database from multi-line sed output

Tags: bash, sed, sqlite

I am running this:

```
sed -ne '/###SECTION-1###/,/###SECTION-2###/p file
```

And it outputs this:

```
###SECTION-1###

ColumnA: 1a
ColumnB: 2b
ColumnC: 3c
ColumnA: Z9
ColumnB: Y8
ColumnC: X7

###SECTION-2###
```

I want to create a sqlite database using the above output so that it looks like this:

```
ColumnA  ColumnB  ColumnC
-------  -------  -------
1a       2b       3c
Z9       Y8       X7
```

I figure the sqlite insert command will look something like the below, but I am having trouble assigning $columna, $columnb, $columnc from the original sed command.

```
sqlite3 /tmp/test.db "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO data (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC) values ('$columna', '$columnb', '$columnc');"
```

How do I assign $columna, $columnb, $columnc ?

Comment: the sqlite3 command works, I am stumped on assigning $columna, $columnb, $columnc from the original output.  Perhaps a better way to phrase the question is "how to assign variables from multi-line output?"

Comment: When you say, from the "original awk command". What awk command?

Comment: @jas fixed - this is sed output

Comment: I have 2 examples in my question.  The first is the output I am getting from sed.  The second is how I would like to see that output formatted as a sqlite3 table.  Does that make sense?  I am sorry it is not more clear.

Comment: No. You want a tool that will take some file that you haven't shown us the contents of and output either a table or maybe a command that generates a table (?). Just clean up your question to show **THE INPUT** you want a tool to read (not some sed output you don't want) and **THE OUTPUT** you want it to produce (not a choice of 2 possible final outputs or something else you hope to be able to produce later with this tools output). Just make it clear and simple for us - a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input file and the associated expected output given that input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that with `awk` ,it is far easier to read (and write) than `sed` IMHO:

```
awk '/^ColumnA:/{a=$2}
     /^ColumnB:/{b=$2}
     /^ColumnC:/{c=$2; printf("sqlite2 /tmp/test/db \"INSERT (ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC) values ('\''%s'\'','\''%s'\'','\''%s'\'');\"\n",a,b,c)}' file.txt
```

So, when we see a line starting with `"ColumnA:"`, we save the second field as `a`. When we see a line starting with `"ColumnB:"`, we save the second field as `b`. When we see a line starting with `"ColumnC:"`, we save the second field as `c` and print the SQL stuff (which I have abbreviated for clarity.

**Sample Output**

```
sqlite2 /tmp/test/db "INSERT (ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC) values ('1a','2b','3c');"
sqlite2 /tmp/test/db "INSERT (ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC) values ('Z9','Y8','X7');"
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
awk '/^ColumnA:/{a=$2} /^ColumnB:/{b=$2} /^ColumnC:/{c=$2; printf("sqlite2 /tmp/test/db \"INSERT (ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC) values ('\''%s'\'','\''%s'\'','\''%s'\'');\"\n",a,b,c)}' file.txt
```

If that looks correct, you can send the output to `bash` for actual execution:

```
awk '{...}' file.txt | bash
```

Comment: This is fantastic and exactly what I needed.  Thank you very much!

Comment: My pleasure - glad to be of assistance. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

You did not say you wanted to use `sed` for further processing, and [multiline replacements are not easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801921/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-multiline-string), but it's possible.

First, remove the SECTION lines.
Then replace the `ColumnX:` texts with the appropriate parts of the SQL statement:

```
sed -ze "s/ColumnA: /INSERT OR IGNORE INTO data(ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC) VALUES('/g;s/\nColumnB: /', '/g;s/\nColumnC: \([^\n]*\)\n/', '\1');\n/g"
```